# How to run auto-upgrade of ArangoDB 3.1 to 3.2 on docker image

Tags: docker, arangodb

When trying to upgrade a docker container with ArangoDB 3.1 to 3.2 I run into the issue with the database needing upgrade:

`FATAL Database '_system' needs upgrade. Please start the server with the --database.auto-upgrade option
FATAL Database '_system' upgrade failed. Please inspect the logs from the upgrade procedure`

How do I actually pass the setting? I tried setting `command: 'arangod --database.auto-upgrade true` in my `docker-compose.yml`, but that does nothing.

Answer (score 10):

I also use docker-compose for my system in which arangodb is run under service name `database` like this:

`version: '2.1'
   services:
     database:
       image: arangodb:3.1.3
       ports:
         - 8529:8529
       volumes:
         - /opt/my-system/Database/arangodb:/var/lib/arangodb3
         - /opt/my-system/Database/arangodb-apps:/var/lib/arangodb3-apps
       restart: always
       healthcheck:
         test: curl -f my-system:8529/_api/version || exit 1
.
.
. other services`

Before upgrading, I also have to stop my system.
I have just upgraded my arangodb container with the following steps (3.1.3 => 3.2.5)

1. `docker pull arangodb:3.2.5` => get the image you want to upgrade to
2. `docker-compose stop` => stop my system which uses the database
3. backup the database volumes (I just make a copy of /opt/my-system/Database folder)
4. `docker-compose rm -f database` => remove the container running old arangodb
5. update docker-compose.yml file with new arangodb image => so  `image:arangodb:3.1.3` becomes `image:arangodb:3.2.5`
6. `docker-compose run --rm database arangod --database.auto-upgrade` => this will create the database container running v3.2.5, upgrade the database files, then remove the container when it is done.
7. `docker-compose up -d database` => start the upgraded database to see if everything is OK
8. `docker-compose start` => start the rest of the system, which now uses the upgraded database

If I had errors during upgrade, I could have easily rolled back to v3.1.3, as I always keep the prev image and the database files.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the auto upgrade with your .yaml configuration:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  resilient_single:
      image: arangodb/arangodb
      ports:
        - '8003:8529'
        - '8004:8539'
        - '8005:8549'
      command: arangod --database.auto-upgrade
```

The [`--database.auto-upgrade`](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/programs-arangod-options.html#database) option can be enabled just by being declared (you don't need the value `true`).

Example usage of `arangodb` options can be found in the .yaml configuration of [arangoX](https://github.com/ArangoDB-Community/arangox/blob/master/docker-compose.yml)